# can't create a string with single backslash in python

Tags: python

I want to create the following string in python

```
path ="\\a\c\d\l"
```

when I check the value of path I get

```
>>> path
'\\a\\c\\d\\l'
```

when I print the value of path I get

```
>>> print(path)
\a\c\d\l
```

I tried to define path also as follows

```
path ="\\\\a\\c\\d\\l"
```

but the results I get are

```
>>> path
'\\\\a\\c\\d\\l'

>>> print(path)
\\a\c\d\l
```

(it seems like this is what I want but the actual value contains double backslashes as shown above)

this path is a path to a shared folder the path should be in the format `\\a\c\d\l` but none of the python string manage to create this format and I can't access this folder.

Does someone have solution for this problem?

Comment: `(it seems like this is what I want but the actual value contains double backslashes as shown above)` No. The actual value is what you see when printing it.

Comment: The second way is what you want. The actual value (as you can see when printing it) does not contain double backslashes. The representation as string literal does, but that doesn't matter. If you can't access the folder the problem likely lies elsewhere (for example missing credentials), but to help you there we'd need to know what error you get.

Comment: You could alleviate your path construction woes by using [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) it's pretty convenient and the Paths can be used anywhere python expects a pathlike object.

Comment: the fact is that i can't access the folder with the second way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a raw string to not encounter this problem:

```
path = r"\\a\c\d\l"
```

Comment: this is what i get when i try this. 
path = r"\\a\c\d\l"
path
'\\\\a\\c\\d\\l'
still not what i want

Comment: oh, actually it seems like raw string doesn't give me what i want but when i try to access the file i succeed. thank you

Comment: If this is the solution you were looking for, please do accept it :)

Comment: @AlbinSidås, they probably won't accept either my or yours answer, but they are both working so... +1

Comment: sorry, i tried to vote to this answer but github said i need more reputation, is there other way to do it?

Comment: @bareluz As you are the one making the question you can mark an answer as the accepted answer, which is what me and FLAK-ZOSO is refering to. You may need higher reputation before you can upvote.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> path
'\\\\a\\c\\d\\l'
>>> print(path)
\\a\c\d\l
```

Did you notice that in your `path` string there are 4 `\` at the beginning? That's why there are two backslashes at the beginning instead of one.

---

You can write a single backslash in Python *excaping it*:

```
>>> print("\\ <- backslash")
\ <- backslash
```

or using a `raw-string`:

```
>>> print(r"\ <- backslash")
\ <- backslash
```

Comment: thank you, i noticed that, but raw string didn't work

Comment: oh, actually it seems like raw string doesn't give me what i want but when i try to access the file i succeed. thank you

Comment: If my answer worked it's a good practice to accept it, if it didn't work feel free to ask more :) welcome to stack overflow anyway